# using list of word in function pandas extract

Tags: python, pandas, string, list

I have list of word to search in dataframe with regex. I try to another way to use function extract without writing all the list in braket. Any idea plz?

```
df["description"].str.extract("(SECTION.?\dRADÔME|PROFONDEUR ET TAB|PRINCIPAL GAUCHE|PRINCIPAL DROIT|PLAN FIXE VERTICAL|PLAN FIXE HORIZONTAL|MOTEUR|KARMAN|HÉLICE|GOUVERNAIL ET TAB|CÔNE ARRIÈRE)")
```

I try to use join but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why it didn't work?

Comment: I want to use loop to do that without using join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list of words and create a pattern to use with extract:

```
words = [r'SECTION.?\dRADÔME',
        'PROFONDEUR ET TAB',
        'PRINCIPAL GAUCHE',
        'PRINCIPAL DROIT',
        'PLAN FIXE VERTICAL',
        'PLAN FIXE HORIZONTAL',
        'MOTEUR',
        'KARMAN',
        'HÉLICE',
        'GOUVERNAIL ET TAB',
        'CÔNE ARRIÈRE']

pattern = fr"({'|'.join(words)})"

df["description"].str.extract(pattern)
```